# Android in app billing - can't test real product ID purchase

Tags: android, billing

I'm implementing in app  billing in my app. I've followed the example provided by Google and I believe everything is in order. The problem I'm facing is when I try to test a real purchase (with my own product ID), I'm able to get to the Google checkout of my in app product, but every credit card I try to use on any test account, is not excepted (grayed out stating "This payment method has been declined"). It seems that my developer account is just not accepting credit cards.
My checkout account is active and my adSense bank account is verified.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there were issues with my checkout-merchant account. Google asked me to create a new developer account and it is working now.

Comment: from how you get real product id? i cannot found any where i am testing inapp purchase till yet i am using android.test.purchased now i want to use my product id so from where i can get it?